# Query Firebase by date when not all keys have the child

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've got tasks with an optional `assignedDay` child.  When I use `ref.child('tasks').orderByChild('assignedDay').endAt([timestamp])` where timestamp is the time I'm trying to limit to, I get back all tasks with no `assignedDay` child.  I didn't expect this.  Is there any way to limit the query to only values that have an `assignedDay` child, or do I need to set an additional `scheduled` child to filter by?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't specify a start of the range query, the database returns all children from the start of the collection up to the end value you specified.

You'd use `startAt` in combination with `endAt` for this.

```
ref.child('tasks')
   .orderByChild('assignedDay')
   .startAt(0)
   .endAt([timestamp])
```

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#data-order